# Vercel now server doesn't work with google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

I am trying to create a simple express server which adds some data to a google sheet when something is post requested on the link. Everything works locally but on now, the request works but it doesn't add data to the doc.

**Index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const base64 = require("base-64");

app.use(cors());
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");
const creds = require("./client_secret.json");
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(
  "11...."
);

async function accessSpreadsheet(depts, email) {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: creds.client_email,
    private_key: creds.private_key,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
  console.log(doc.title);
  console.log(depts);

  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
  const rows = await sheet.getRows(); // or use doc.sheetsById[id]
  console.log(sheet.title);
  console.log(sheet.rowCount);

  await sheet.loadCells("B1:C500");
  depts.forEach((value) => {
    var a1 = sheet.getCell(value.id + 1, 2);
    a1.value += ", " + email;
  });
  sheet.saveUpdatedCells();
}

app.post(
  "/form/:email/",
  (req, res, next) => {
    const email = base64.decode(req.params.email);
    const depts = JSON.parse(req.query.array);
    accessSpreadsheet(depts, email);
    next();
  },
  (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params + "success!");
  }
);

app.post("/form/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("please send post req");
});

app.get("/form/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("please send post req");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("e-Lite reg api");
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${3000}!`));
```

**now.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@now/node-server" }],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/",
      "dest": "/index.js",
      "methods": ["GET"]
    },
     {
       "src": "/form.*",
       "dest": "/index.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST"]
     }
  ]
}
```

I dont think theres any problem with the code. It all works locally. Zeit doesn't report any errors with the API.

Comment: [@now/node-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@now/node-server) is deprecated, use [@vercel/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/node) instead.

Comment: how do I deploy expressJS on @vercel/node

Comment: Try removing express and instead use [Node.js helpers](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-request-and-response-objects) which are very similar to express.